# Maven Clean Install Error

Tags: maven

I am very new to maven and I am getting an error once I am running `mvn clean install` command after `svn checkout`. `mvn clean install` can't find some files and outputs extraneous stack trace which clog up the output.

```
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException:
```

In case of running the `sudo mvn clean install`, I am not getting those exceptions. Is there any other way to clean these filenotfound without adding a `sudo` command?

With Regards,
Kumardip

Comment: it seems there is a path configured that stores a file in a directory you have no permission to use. Just change that to a writable path, then the sudo should not be required anymore. The stacktrace should also print what file it was looking for (and its path). Usually I would think there is a property or configuration setting that would avoid this. So maybe there is a readme that points to that?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will try this process and update soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can split up the clean process and the build into different steps.
First try

```
mvn clean
```

Normally all the directories to be cleaned will be directories you just made with svn checkout or made by running mvn install.
You tried sudo, so now you can have files/dirs owned by root under your current directory.
When you are sure that your current dir is yours, you can start with something like

```
sudo chown -R kumardip *
```

(Replace by the current username)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Walter, but I am looking for a process to remove these errors other than changing the permissions. Could you please suggest something for that ?

Comment: When you did `svn checkout` with sudo, the errors are caused by files with the root permission. All your files should be yours, so when the local repository is yours, claiming the ownership is correcting errors. When you have a different error, try to find which wtep shows the error: the `mvn clean`or the `mvn install`. (install can be split in substeps too)